# How to put xml code for a subreport in xtrareport devexpress?

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I created a master report file. Then I created subreport file. Is there a way to put xml code of the subreport file as a report source ?

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnBeforePrint` method and go through [`XtraReportBase.Controls`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_Controlstopic) property tree to find `XRSubreport`. As described [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument1183) you can use `DataSet` and its `DataSet.ReadXml` method:

```cs
protected override void OnBeforePrint(PrintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBeforePrint(e);

    //Get your xml here
    var dataSet = new DataSet();

    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        dataSet.ReadXml(reader);

    SetSubReportXML(this, dataSet);
}

private void SetSubReportXML(XRControl xrControl, DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach (XRControl xrControlChild in xrControl.Controls)
    {
        var subReport = xrControlChild as XRSubreport;

        if (subReport != null)
        {
            //Set your xml here
            subReport.ReportSource.DataSource = dataSet;
            subReport.ReportSource.DataMember = this.DataMember;

            SetSubReportXML(subReport.ReportSource, dataSet);
        }

        SetSubReportXML(xrControlChild, dataSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I set xml there . Could you give an example?

Comment: @Revenge94 What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Revenge94 You can use `subReport.ReportSource.XmlDataPath` and `subReport.ReportSource.DataMember` properties.

Comment: I must put xml code not path. This method is available in Telerik Report D. and Crystal Report . But is not available in Devexpress.

Comment: @Revenge94 Sad, but true. Use `DataSet` class and its `DataSet.ReadXml` method.

Comment: can dataset read a report ?. so i will open and repx file with notpad and then copy that  and Dataset.ReadXml("SOURCE THAT I COPIED") is it right ? or can i use dataset.readxml for like customers , orders data ?

Comment: For `string xml` value you can use `StringReader` class: `using (var reader = new StringReader("SOURCE THAT I COPIED")) dataSet.ReadXml(reader);`